# onSelectedItem() returns null on listview.onSelectedItem

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

Java Code:

```
PhoneListAdapter adapter = new PhoneListAdapter(this,brands,models,price);
lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.Id.listView1);    
lv.setAdapter(adapter);        
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Parent,View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"listview clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" 
        android:clickable="true">
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
```

I have done everything, if i push a toast with hardcoded string, it appears, but any methods of listview return null. what am i missing???

Comment: use your position to get the selected Item from the Adapter....

Comment: can you put your full code?

Comment: please remove </LinearLayout> from you xml.

Comment: any methods of listview return null means? can you explain more ?

Comment: Add `android:focusable="true"` for `ListView`.

Comment: in toast i used lv.getSelectedItem().toString(); or getItemAtPostion(pposition); Actually i have to fire an intent at the item click with the data of the item selected. at using lv.setOnItemSelectedListener, nothing happens.. @itsrajesh4uguys

Comment: @MichaelShrestha i did, returns null :(

Comment: You have a custom Adapter So hopefully you will have a custom ArrayList or some other collections to manage. In the onItemClick get the position then get the value exact index value from that array list.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys i do hv arraylist and i am filing it by from my database, so if i hv to get the name of the selected item, how can i get that out of the arraylist and use it in onclick on listview? :(

Comment: PhoneListAdapter adapter = new PhoneListAdapter(this,brands,models,price);
 here brands, models, price are arraylists ?

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys yes i am getting data in them from my DB in this activity and using them in PhoneLiatAdapter to set in a textview

Comment: @PiyushGupta dint work

Comment: @Slash Are you using custom layout for ListView? If yes show that xml.

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, i have a layout i am using in PhoneListAdapter class, it contains only a TextView

Comment: Show that xml file in which ur textview is

Comment: if they are arraylists and they are holding values they you can get the selected postion values like below. brands.get(index).get... if you have any getter setter use those to get the selected postion values.

Comment: @Slash If you post xml i have alternate solution for it

Comment: It Worked!! Thank you sooooo much @itsrajesh4uguys.. I was trying getSelectedItemAtPosition(position), ignored the array adapter, and that created the problem.. thankssss :)

Comment: I have given this as answer below . Please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Use somethid like below, if brands,models,price are arrayLists.

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);        
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> Parent,View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Assign the String or integer what ever you want. = brands .get(position).get if you have getter and setter methods. 

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"listview clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Piyush Gupta

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#33ffffff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.

Comment: @Zefnus ok, will do from next time, thnk you :)